# To use If in where clause in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure with 3 parameters and my where clause changes depending on one of these parameteres. Is it possible to write a SQL query in this way -

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VendorVettingModal] @column NVarchar (50), @applicanttype NVarchar (10), @donotuse int AS

                declare @column NVarchar (50), @applicanttype NVarchar (10), @donotuse int

    select a.Id, a.Firstname, rs.Status,cs.ClearanceStatus
    from applicant a 
    left join ReviewStatus rs on a.ReviewStatus = rs.Id 
    left join ClearanceStatus cs on a.ClearanceStatus = cs.Id
    where
    if(@column = 'Recruiting')
    begin
        a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and a.reviewstatus = 7 and a.donotuse = @donotuse      
    end
    else if(@column = 'Clearance')
    begin
        a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and (a.reviewstatus != 7 or a.reviewstatus is null) and a.donotuse = @donotuse     
    end
```

Rather than writing this way? Because I have about 20-25 columns and a lot more joins and where params than defined here. I have just tried to make it less complicated here.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VendorVettingModal] @column NVarchar (50), @applicanttype NVarchar (10), @donotuse int AS

                declare @column NVarchar (50), @applicanttype NVarchar (10), @donotuse int

    if(@column = 'Recruiting')
    begin
        select a.Id, a.Firstname, rs.Status,cs.ClearanceStatus
        from applicant a 
        left join ReviewStatus rs on a.ReviewStatus = rs.Id 
        left join ClearanceStatus cs on a.ClearanceStatus = cs.Id
        where
        a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and a.reviewstatus = 7 and a.donotuse = @donotuse      
    end
    else if(@column = 'Clearance')
    begin
        select a.Id, a.Firstname, rs.Status,cs.ClearanceStatus
        from applicant a 
        left join ReviewStatus rs on a.ReviewStatus = rs.Id 
        left join ClearanceStatus cs on a.ClearanceStatus = cs.Id
        where
        a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and (a.reviewstatus != 7 or a.reviewstatus is null) and a.donotuse = @donotuse     
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
 select a.Id, a.Firstname, rs.Status,cs.ClearanceStatus
    from applicant a 
    left join ReviewStatus rs on a.ReviewStatus = rs.Id 
    left join ClearanceStatus cs on a.ClearanceStatus = cs.Id
    where a.applicanttype = @applicanttype
    and a.donotuse = @donotuse 
    AND ((@column = 'Recruiting' AND (a.reviewstatus = 7))
    OR
    (@column = 'Clearance' AND (a.reviewstatus != 7 or a.reviewstatus is null)))
```

Comment: You could probably improve it a little by factoring out `a.applicanttype = @applicanttype` and  `a.donotuse = @donotuse `

Comment: msmucker0527: Awesome works just as i want, actually i have one more if going in the if(@column = 'Recruiting') 
but i am able to implement it using the paranthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this two ways.  One way uses dynamic SQL.  However, that is not generalizable to any database.  The alternative is to structure the WHERE clause as:

```
where (case when @column = 'Recruiting' and
                 a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and a.reviewstatus = 7 and a.donotuse = @donotuse
            then 'True'
            when @column = 'Clearance' and
                 a.applicanttype = @applicanttype and (a.reviewstatus != 7 or a.reviewstatus is null) and a.donotuse = @donotuse
            then 'True'
            . . .
       end) = 'True'
```

Two advantages of this over dynamic SQL is that the query does not have to be recompiled and it works in a broader range of databases.  One disadvantage is that the WHERE clause *may* not take advantage of applicable indexes.

Comment: The first advantage doesn't exist if you parameterise your dynamic sql (and you always should), as SQL Server *will* cache the query plan just like static sql.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunalety, in transact-sql the "if-else-if-else" only can write this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx

```
DECLARE @Number int;
SET @Number = 50;
IF @Number > 100
   PRINT 'The number is large.';
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        IF @Number < 10
            PRINT 'The number is small.';
        ELSE
            PRINT 'The number is medium.';
    END;
GO
```

It's complicated, but only this way is possible